# Unobtrusive jQuery unobtrusive validation not showing error spans

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I realise there are heaps of SO posts on this subject, and I have read and applied any suggestions I have seen in them where applicable, however nothing seems to work. I have been banging my head against this for a while now and just cannot see where the error is. I am hoping someone can point out what I cannot see.

I have the an MVC 5 application. The client side validation is working in that if I don't fill in what is needed the form will not post. However, the span tags to show the errors are not being generated upon error. Here is what I have:

**web.config**

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

**Generated HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap-3.3.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/content/themes/jquery-ui-bootstrap/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/booking/process" id="idFrmBooking" method="post">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-email="Enter a valid email address." data-val-required="Enter your email address." id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" type="text" value="" />
    </form> 

    <script src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap-3.3.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery-ui.unobtrusive-3.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery.inputmask/inputmask.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery.inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

So as a simple test I type in either nothing or an invalid email address into the input field and get no error message. Anyone?

Comment: Because you have not generated the element needed to display the message i.e. using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress)`

Comment: But the original input is generated with a **@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress)** so that takes care of that?

Comment: No it does not. That generates the `<input>` element only, not the `<span>` element. jQuery validation does not create the element, its just add the error message inside it. `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress)` will generate the necessary `<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="EmailAddress" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>` needed as  placeholder to display the message

Comment: OK, that is **really** odd as I have another project that has no **ValidationMessageFor()** calls in it and I am getting the spans generated just from the **TextBoxFor()** calls. Those calls are standard HTML helpers, nothing special. So is there anything else that can affect the generation of the spans that you know of? (PS. Putting in the ValidationMessageFor() does indeed generate the expected result)

Comment: `TextBoxFor()` will **not** generate anything other than a `<input type="text" ... />` element. If they are being generated, its because of other code you have.

Comment: Thanks. If you want to post your comment as an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form does not contain the necessary `<span>` element that acts as the placeholder for the message generated by jQuery validation.

You need to include

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
```

which will output

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="EmailAddress" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Comment: Excellent, that wasn't my problem however, mine was that I've used `div` instead of `span` and it didn't work!